# LibGDX - Represent a Perspective Camera as a Quaternion

Tags: java, math, libgdx, quaternions

How would you represents the rotation of a LibGDX [Perspective Camera](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/utils/PerspectiveCamController.java) as a [Quaternion](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Quaternion rotation = camera.view.getRotation(new Quaternion());`